# Why "print" doesn't work in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I have `JavsScript` code with function `print`. It works correctly in console of web browser, but when I run this code using node i obtain error:

```
ReferenceError: print is not defined
```

Of course I can use `console.log`, but I would like to know why `print` is not implemented in `node`?

Comment: Provide some code, please.

Comment: Program with code: `print("test");` gives error `ReferenceError: print is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/print.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3`

Comment: what does print do in the console of the browser for you? ... because global print in a browser sends the current page to a printer - not sure how this can translate to a node.js application - what exactly would that send to a printer?

Comment: @Daniel - what would you like print to actually do?

Comment: @Daniel edit the code into your question, don't put them in comments.

Comment: This has nothing to do with printing by printer. I study javascript from probably to old book... I checked that in other one only "colsole.log" is used... Any way I was interested only if print is depreciated or maybe there is other reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `print` or [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) opens the Print Dialog to print the current document.

In Contrast, the [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) outputs a message to the Web Console.

If your intention was to actually print a file to a 'hardware printer', from Node.js then have a look at projects such as [`node-printer`](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer).

Comment: Speaking of `console.log()`, was able to get `console.log fooFunction(x)` (without braces) to print to terminal emulator using a `coffeescript` interactive shell from the Debian repo. And used `coffee` command to run a script.

Answer (score 1):

`window.print()` opens the printer dialog of the browser to print the current page. It does *not* print something to the console. See the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print). Hence it is not what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

`print()` prints document rendered by browser. There are no documents in nodejs to print.

Answer (score -5):

1. Install SpiderMonkey in Ubuntu 16.04-17.10 open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install libmozjs-24-0v5 libmozjs-24-bin
   ```
2. To start Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine, which can also be used as an interactive 
   interpreter, from the terminal type:

   ```
   js24
   ```
3. To exit from js24:

   ```
   quit()
   ```

Comment: The question is asking why Node.js doesn't support the `print` function. Your answer is about installing SpiderMonkey (which is not Node.js) and doesn't mention the `print` function at all. Did you type your answer in the answer box on the wrong question?

Comment: The question is asking why Node.js doesn't support the `print` function. Your answer is about installing SpiderMonkey (which is not Node.js) and doesn't mention the `print` function at all. Did you type your answer in the answer box on the wrong question?